# Android MediaPlayer Error (1, -2147483648) CFContent MP4 Video

Tags: android, video, coldfusion, mp4, cfml

I have an Android app that plays MP4 files using the VideoView.  The videos are pulled from a remote server and provided to the VideoView object using the .setVideoURI() method.  They are Baseline encoded and play fine when I provide the setVideoURI method with a direct link to the mp4 file.  However, I need to find a way to make it work using the ColdFusion cfcontent tag.  At the moment, I have the cfcontent tag set up as follows

```
<cfcontent type="video/mp4" file="full path to my mp4 file" deleteFile="no">
```

This works fine in a browser, however when I try to provide a link to my CFM page as the URI for the setVideoURI method, it comes back with the MediaPlayer Error (1, -2147483648) and also shows the same error for the VideoView.  I'ved tried adding cfheader tags prior to the cfcontent to force the type as video/mp4, but with no success.

```
11-14 15:05:18.162: E/MediaPlayer(373): error (1, -2147483648)
11-14 15:05:18.162: E/MediaPlayer(373): Error (1,-2147483648)
11-14 15:05:18.162: D/VideoView(373): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Has anyone had success playing MP4 files in a Android VideoView using a ColdFusion page and the cfcontent tag?  Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated!!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Android has very specific encoding requirements for MP4, one being that the video must be baseline profile encoded.  Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html for more information.  I re-encoded the video using baseline profile and it worked correctly.